# MapView with iframe code

Tags: ios, ios4, iframe, mkmapview

Can anyone guide how to display map on MapView with iframe code. I try to search in google and this site and there still no guide for me.

My app is get iframe from server and need to show map into UIMapview(or there has better way ??)

So please help me guide to code it. ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer. Just parse  and get url from tag src in